# Is there an alternative for UDDI?

Tags: web-services, discovery, uddi

I know that UDDI gives the posibility of descovering a web service. Is there any alternative for UDDI that do the same thing : to discover web services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDDI is out of the scene these days. People are moving towards semantic web services. [WSMO](http://www.wsmo.org/) and OWL-s are major initiatives for semantic web services. These solutions can provide more precise results.

Comment: WSMO is thing to give try instead of UDDI

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few

- mDNS/Bonjour/Avahi - can be used to share endpoint information for a web service, or anything else using a TXT record
- WS-Discovery - supported by CXF and WCF, shares implementation of a specific interface
- ebXML - had a component similar to UDDI